# Tracking websites that link to my app in the apple AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store, affiliate

I would like to track which websites link to my app in the app store.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple do not provide metrics and I'd say they would frown on any attempts to insert analytics code into your description.

Use of Google Alerts for your app name and possibly and inurl:appID might help.